# Transform checkbox boolean to text and send it in a get request to api

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, transform, get-request

I have a school project where im building a recipe search application with angular for frontend and laravel for backend and fetches the recipes from edamams API. I want to be able to filter my searches with some checkboxes and transform the "true" value to a text that i put in my searchquery. I have a object where the properties are the checkboxes and have a initial value of false which turn true when checked.

How do i transform this true value to a text like '&dishType=starter'? and also how do i check if some of the properties in my object are true and then send the text to my searchquery?

This is my searchform:

```
            <input id="search-box" type="text" (keyup.enter)="getRecipes()" [(ngModel)]="searchquery">
            <label for="starter" class="filter">
                <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="starter" [(ngModel)]="filter.starter">
                <span> Starter</span>
            </label>
            <label for="main" class="filter">
                <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="main" [(ngModel)]="filter.main">
                <span>Main</span>
            </label>
            <label for="dessert" class="filter">
                <input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="dessert" [(ngModel)]="filter.dessert">
                <span class="checkbox-text">Dessert</span>
            </label>
 <button type="button" (click)="getRecipes();">Search</button>
```

and this is my object:

```
filter = {
    starter: false,
    main: false,
    dessert: false,
  };
```

and my function to get the recipes:

```
getRecipes() {
    this.loadRecipes = true; // Ignore
    this.recipeShow = false; // Ignore
    console.log(
      this.filter.starter,
      this.filter.main,
      this.filter.dessert,
    );
    this.recipeService
      .getRecipes(this.searchquery, // Here is where i want to put the filter values)
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.recipeShow = true; // Ignore
        this.loadRecipes = false; // Ignore
        let searchedWord = this.searchquery; // Ignore
        let recipes = result.hits.map((data: any) => {
          let recipe = data.recipe;
          recipe.idref = data._links.self.href.slice(38, 70);
          return recipe;
        });
        
        this.allRecipes = recipes;
        
        this.word = searchedWord;
      });
  }
```

And here is my function in my recipe.service.ts:

```
getRecipes(q: string, filter: string) {
    let searchquery =
      this.urlConfig +
      '?type=public&q=' +
      q +
      '&app_id=' +
      this.appid +
      '&app_key=' +
      this.appkey +
      filter +
      '&field=label' +
      '&field=idref' +
      '&field=image' +
      '&field=ingredientLines' +
      '&field=yield' +
      '&field=shareAs' +
      '&field=totalTime' +
      '&field=healthLabels' +
      '&field=dietLabels' +
      '&field=mealType' +
      '&field=dishType' +
      '&field=cuisineType';
    return this.http.get<any>(searchquery, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert a boolean to a string with `'' + booleanValue` or `'someString=' + booleanValue`.

But in this case, I am not sure you are going in the right direction. Angulars HttpClient and Laravel will do all the converting for you. You should look into sending POST requests. What you do is create an Object with all the parameters you need and mirror that object in the backend.

So you would have something like:

```
filterObject = {
  starter: false,
  main: false,
  dessert: false,
  field: ['label', 'image', ...],
};
```

and in the service you call:

```
return this.httpClient.post<any>(
   `${this.urlConfig}/path-to-rest?api_id=1&api_key=2`, 
   filterObject
);
```

Make sure you are using JSON format for sending and recieving.